# Admob not giving videos options

Tags: android, admob, video-ads

I've implemented admob in my application, However when I visit the [page](https://apps.admob.com/#monetize/adunit:edit/id=myappid)  I am getting adtype only text and images, no videos. How Can I get to include video ads in my application? or is it something you get rewarded after a period of time?

Comment: http://s21.postimg.org/wbib69u2v/Screen_Shot_2016_09_20_at_8_48_16_AM.png

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Monetize -> Select your app -> Click the interstitial ad unit -> Enable/Disable ad types. Select all the three images/text/Video and click save

Comment: Yeh, Check my Post. I am doing exactly that. But my ad types only has images, text  no videos.

Comment: http://s21.postimg.org/wbib69u2v/Screen_Shot_2016_09_20_at_8_48_16_AM.png?

Comment: oops sorry i got it, i need to create new ad interstial id.thank you